# How to remove first few digits from order id using order id variable in email template

Tags: magento2, email-templates, variables, custom-variable

I am using a 3rd party plugin for order number customization and the format I am using is-        {order id}-{counter}AB
e.g.   1234-30000AB

In the email template when I include order id variable it is picking the whole order number, i.e. 1234-30000AB
whereas I only want to include the first four digits, i.e., 1234.

Is there a way I can create a string filter to remove last the last 7 digits

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Observed event **email_order_set_template_vars_before** and add your new increament id and create new order email template from existing one and update it accordingly.

**event.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="email_order_set_template_vars_before">
    <observer name="add_extra_data_to_transport" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddExtraDataToTransport" />
  </event>
</config>
```

**AddExtraDataToTransport.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddExtraDataToTransport implements ObserverInterface
{  
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $transport = $observer->getEvent()->getTransport();
        $order = $transpost['order'];
        $transport['new_increament_id'] = substr($order->getIncreamentId(), 0, 4);
    }
}
```

Create a new email template by loading existing one and change $order.increment_id to $new_increament_id. I am sure it'll work. Let me know if you need further assistance for the same.

Happy Coding :)